# Can I grant admin access to an Azure resource group and Synapse workspace for an account in a different directory and subscription?

Tags: azure, subscription, access-control

I have a resource group in one of my accounts that has Visual Studio Professional subscription. In the resource group I have several resources including a Synapse workspace.

I have another account with a Pay as you Go subscription and I would like to grant admin access to the mentioned resource group for this account. I would like to be able to edit, test and run everything from both accounts.

Is this possible to do? If so, how?
Also, could that other account be an Azure trial account too?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to assume that you have two accounts that belong to two different Azure AD (AAD) tenants (let's say Visual Studio-tenant and PayAsGo-tenant).

Azure subscriptions can only be attached to a single AAD tenant that will manage the Azure RBAC for it. This means you would need to have both users in the Visual Studio -tenant to make this work.

If you have admin rights available for that Visual Studio -tenant, you can solve your problem by inviting your user from the PayAsGo-tenant [as a guest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-users-administrator) and granting it the required rights (most straightforward is Contributor rights to the Synapse resource group).